# Cooley-Tukey FFT Algorithm in Python (no Numpy) Index Error

Tags: python, algorithm, fft

I am tasked with using the Cooley-Tukey algorithm to implement the Fourier transform on some signal data. I'm not allowed to use the Numpy module so I must implement the algorithm myself. However, by following the pseudocode I was given, I'm getting a "IndexError: list index out of range" error when I try to run it. The signal is a list of 512 elements. Below is my code. The error occurs at "t=sig[k+m]-sig[k+m+r]"

```
def fft(sig,d):
    N=len(sig)
    theta = (-2*math.pi*d)/N
    r=N//2
    for i in range(1,N):
        omega=math.cos(i*theta)+j*math.sin(i*theta)
        for k in range(0,N):
            u = 1
            for m in range(0,r):
                t=sig[k+m]-sig[k+m+r]
                sig[k+m] = sig[k+m] + sig[k+m+r]
                sig[k+m+r]=t*u
                u=omega*u
            k=k+2*r
        i=2*i
        r=r/2
    for i in range(0,N):
        r=i
        k=0
        for m in range(1,N):
            k=2*k+(r%2)
            r=r/2
            m=2*m
        if k>i:
            t=sig[i]
            sig[i]=sig[k]
            sig[k]=t
    if d<0:
        for i in range(0,N):
            sig[i]=sig[i]/N
```

I understand that k+m eventually gets larger than 512 (the size of the signal) and thats what the error is, but I'm honestly just following the pseudocode. I know I am making some kind of stupid mistake somewhere. 
Thank you for any help!
Oh, the pseudo code (up to where the error occurs), directly from my source, is

```
1. set theta = -2pi*d/N and r = N/2
2.For i=1 to N-1 do
  {
   (a) set omega = cos(i*theta)+jsin(i*theta)
   (b) For k=0 to N-1 do
       {
        (1) Set u=1
        (2) For m=0 to r-1 do
            {
             t = z(k+m) - z(k+m+r)
             z(k+m) = z(k+m) + z(k+m+r)
             z(k+m+r) = tu
             u=omega*u
            }
        (3) Set k=k+2r
        }
   (c) Set i = 2i and k=0
   }
 3. For i=0 to N-1 do
    {
     (a) Set r = i and k = 0
     (b) For m=1 to N-1 do
         {
          k=2k+(r%2)
          r=r/2
          m=2m
         }
     (c) if k > i do
         {
          t=z(i)
          z(i)=z(k)
          z(k) = t
         }
     }
  4. If d < 0 then for i=0 to N-1 do
     {
        z(i)=z(i)/n
     }
```

I guess I should add that z (pseudocode) and my signal is Nx1 vector of values, with N = 512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the index error, is that you are using k, and i, in your for loops, but then the algorithm is also modifying these variables with the statements.

> ```
>    k=k+2*r
>  i=2*i
> ```

Be aware that the python for range statement does not work like a traditional C style for loop here, and will just continue to iterate through the range with a stride of one, regardless of how you manipulate the iterator within the loop.

Edit, here is a version that at least runs to completion. 
But **NOTE:** that I don't believe it produces the correct results. You can use it as a starting point and then compare to results from numpy, octave or your favorite math suite.

```
import math 
import cmath

d=1
z=[1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0]
N=len(z)
theta = -2*math.pi*d/N 
r = math.floor(N/2)
i=1

while i < N-1: #2.For i=1 to N-1 do
    omega = math.cos(i*theta)+ cmath.sin(i*theta)
    k=0
    while k < N-1: #For k=0 to N-1 do
        u=1
        m=0
        while m < r-1 :#For m=0 to r-1 do
            t = z[k+m] - z[k+m+r]
            z[k+m] = z[k+m] + z[k+m+r]
            z[k+m+r] = t*u
            u=omega*u
            m=m+1
        k=k+2*r
    i = 2*i 
i=0
while i < N-1:#For i=0 to N-1 do
    r = i 
    k = 0
    m=1
    while m < N-1: # For m=1 to N-1 do
        k=math.floor(2*k+(r%2))
        r=r/2
        m=2*m

    if k > i:
        t=z[i]
        z[i]=z[k]
        z[k] = t

    i=i+1

if d < 0:
    i=0
    while i < N-1: #  for i=0 to N-1:
        z[i]=z[i]/N
        i=i+1
i=0
while i < N-1:   
    print("z[i]",z[i].real, z[i].imag);
    i=i+1;
```

Comment: Well, my error that stops the process is occurring at the "t=sig[k+m]-sig[k+m+r]" so if I can get past that I can find out if what you mentioned is an error

Comment: Should I just post the entire pseudocode? I might as well do that

Comment: Are you sure that the error occurs on the first iteration? Either way I'd recommend converting the for loop to while statements and figure out what j is supposed to be, it is currently undefined in your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its supposed to be creating a complex number in Python.. or am I wrong?